# Comparing pairs of rows and remove duplicate information if conditions are met in R

Tags: r, rows

I am quite new to R and I can't come up with a proper solution to the following problem. I have a data frame looking like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(group1 = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A"),
                   group2 = c("B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
                   value = c(22, 22, 75, 84, 84, 75))
mydf
```

I would like to basically compare each pair of rows and remove those rows with redundant information, that is remove rows if group1[row_n] is equal to group2[row_m] and group2[row_n] is equal to group1[row_m] and value[row_n] is equal to value[row_m]. In the example the final data frame should look like:

```
final.df <- data.frame(group1 = c("A","C", "C"), 
                       group2 = c("B", "A", "B"), 
                       value = c(22, 84, 75))
final.df
```

Hope somebody can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `unique(mydf)`?

Comment: I don't think `unique(mydf)` will work since group 1 and group 2 are being treated as interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` and then remove the duplicates like so:

```
df <- data.frame(t(apply(mydf,1,sort)))
final.df <- df[!duplicated(df),]
```

Comment: Thank you @Lucy very neat solution!

Comment: This could have issues if the group and value columns ever have similar items

Comment: Could you make an example of the issues @andrew?

Comment: @Rijak `mydf <- data.frame(group1 = c("A", "B"), group2 = c("B", "C"), value = c("C", "A"))`

Comment: @andrew it's a good point - this is mostly applicable if you have groups (such as those demonstrated) and some numeric value. @d.b I actually think yours could be a bit dangerous - in the example given there happened to only be duplicate values, but if you had a row that was part of the same group but with a different value you'd want that to be included as a separate row (for example if updated to `mydf <- data.frame(group1 = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A","A"), group2 = c("B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C","C"), value = c(22, 22, 75, 84, 84, 75, 90))`, it would drop the row where value = 90.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
my.df.ord <- mydf %>%
             group_by(group1, group2) %>%
             mutate(gr.min = min(as.character(group1), as.character(group2)),
                    gr.max = max(as.character(group1), as.character(group2))) %>%
             ungroup() %>%
             select(gr.min, gr.max, value) %>%
             unique()
```

The `as.character` is required because your `group1`, `group2` appear as factors.